# android ble stops working?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-bluetooth, android-ble

I have a android app that connects to a ble device. The device sends data to the app when a button is pushed on the device. Sometimes the app and the device show that they are connected but when I push the button on the device no data is transmitted to the phone. Why does this occur and how can I fix it?